# Bootstrap datepicker not highlighting date in calendar in edit mode of gridview

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, entity-framework, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used MVCGrid with Edit and delete button in asp.net mvc5  using entity framework. When I click on Edit button,bootstrap modal popup opens up to display data. The date property is displayed correctly but I want the bootstrap calendar to highlight the date selected. Currently it highlights today's date. [image]

Date fetched from database is 11/10/2015 (mm/dd/yyy) and highlighted on calendar is today's date(16th nov). Is there a way to fix this.

My script files used in partial view _Edit is :-

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js">
</script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function (data) {

        $('.datepicker').datepicker(
            {
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                autoclose: true
            }
            );


    });
</script>
```

And this is the code where the date picker is used:-

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })


<div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datepicker" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was that in edit mode my date was printed along with default time. But if it was only date, then it highlights the date in calendar perfectly. Choose the format in datepicker in dateFormat instead of the "format" tag that I used previously. Also in the rendering the TextBox use @Value = Model.Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")(small mm is minutes so use MM here). (For me trying to use the shortdatetimeString here threw error, so I used as above.)

My changes are as below:-

```
<script>
    $(function (data) {

        $('.datepicker').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                pickDate:true,
                autoclose: false
            }
            );

    });
</script>

 <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @Value = Model.Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @class = "datepicker" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: There are many ways to obtain that, your solution has the problem that you need to remember to make this change every time you use datetime, a little better is using EditorTemplates http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, it caused me a lot of headache, I solved definitely with:

```
$('input[type=date]').prop('type', 'text').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    forceParse: false,
    language: "it-IT"
});
```

you need to output your date at the same format, and you can do it in your Web.Config adding `<globalization culture="it-IT" uiCulture="it-IT" />` inside `<system.web>`

Take a look in the source of page of the input of your page, how the date is printed inside the input tag.

Comment: Didnt work for me , but I posted my answer which worked for me. Thanks for replying though :)